# How do you bind database context to datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am new to WPF and quite new to MVVM, I have what I believe to be a correctly structured MVVM project. Only thing I'm unsure about structure wise is what to put in Model vs what to put in ViewModel. Right now I have a Company class inside the CompanyModel file, the data seems redundant but this is where I'm lost for now. Whoever worked on this solution last had set it up this way and it was working, but I needed to changed the app structure into MVVM and now I'm trying to piece it back together.

```
public class CompanyModel
{
    private IList<Company>? _companies;
    private int? _id;
    private string? _name;
    private string? _address;
    private string? _postal;
    private string? _location;
    private string? _country;
    private string? _created;
    private MYSQLDAL.Models.dataContext _context;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
```

...etc.

```
public class Company
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    public string? Postal { get; set; }
    public string? Location { get; set; }
    public string? Country { get; set; }
    public string? Created { get; set; }
}
```

Both of the above snippets are located in CompanyModel.cs

NOTE: For this post, I am just referring to the CompanyModel, CompanyView, and CompanyViewModel, as the others will have the same structure as these.

[image: Project structure]

I have a remote database that I am able to access through another project in the solution. I can pull contexts from it no problem. However, I am note sure on how exactly to bind it to the DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="companyDataGrid"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding CompanyDataGrid, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"
                                    MinWidth="35"
                                    Width="0.1*"
                                    Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                    MinWidth="200"
                                    Width="2*"
                                    Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address"
                                    MinWidth="150"
                                    Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding Address}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Postal/Zip"
                                    MinWidth="150"
                                    Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding Postal}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location"
                                    MinWidth="175"
                                    Width="1.5*"
                                    Binding="{Binding Location}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country"
                                    MinWidth="150"
                                    Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding Country}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Created"
                                    MinWidth="150"
                                    Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding Created}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
```

My DataGrid located in CompanyView.xaml

```
internal class CompanyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CompanyModel> CompanyDataGrid { get; set; }
    private CompanyModel model;
    public CompanyViewModel()
    {
        model = new CompanyModel(new MYSQLDAL.Models.dataContext());
    }
    private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await model.loadCompanies();
    }
    private async void updateDataModel()
    {
        // Update the model
        await model.loadCompanies();
    }
}
```

The CompanyViewModel class located in CompanyViewModel.cs

Basically, I have a database context, and just want to bind it to the grid, even if that's all that happens I can figure more out from there.

I am wanting to have this data grid show the data from the CompanyModel/CompanyViewModel, but I believe I am either misunderstanding what MVVM is, or lack understanding about data binding, or perhaps both. I have scoured the internet looking for someone with a similar probelm to mine and I've found pieces, but so far nothing has seemed to work or trigger a solution in my mind. Could someone assist?

Comment: Please do not link images of your source code.  You can put snippets of code directly into a StackOverflow question.

Comment: I usually have a dto for database data and a viewmodel for use with the view. Even if they are very similar. The dto is a very simple plain class. The dto could be a record. It is immutable. The viewmodel usually inherits from a base viewmodel, has all sorts of things in it. I copy from dto to viewmodel when reading data from db. I copy from viewmodel to new dto when writing. Automapper is useful for this copying in Wpf. ( Less so in web services ).

Comment: @Tarazed Sorry about that, I have made them into code snippets now. Should I do anything with the screenshot of the project structure?

Comment: @Andy I am unfamiliar with dto's sorry, is there somewhere I could find more information or could you explain the concept?

Comment: @ColmUkrainec No that screenshot is fine.

Comment: Dto is just a plain class with properties and nothing else. You should easily find many hits if you search.

Comment: @Andy Okay perfect that's pretty much what I was getting from my searches. One more thing, if a model is built similarly to a dto (basically just properties), wouldn't each instance of the model be one row from the database? In which case, the ViewModel would consist of a collection of Models?

Comment: I never expose a model class to the view. You always implement inotifypropertychanged, often want other things in a viewmodel

Comment: I recommend the mvvm community toolkit nuget package.

Comment: @ColmUkrainec: The `CompanyDataGrid` should probably return an `IEnumerable<Company>`. You use the model to load the data into the view model. Does `model.loadCompanies` return anything, like an `IEnumerable<Company>`?

Comment: It's a code smell to have a `async void` method. This is only allowed for event handlers that must be of type `void`. Every other method must return `Task` or `Task<T>`. For performance reasons you should also make sure that `model.loadCompanies` returns an `ObservableCollection` or in general that the value assigned to `CompanyDataGrid` is an implementation of `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: You must also ensure that the DataContext of the bindings or the DataGrid is the CompanyViewModel. You never showed how and where you set the DataContext of your view. But it seems the context is wrong/unset.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably closer than you think.  I cant see where you are setting the DataContext of your view... to point to the CompanyViewModel class.  I typically would have my set the

```
MyView.DataContext = MyCompanyViewModel;
```

wherever your objects are being created respectively.  Then, whatever is publicly available on the MyCompanyViewModel instance is available for binding to the view similar to what you are attempting.

Now, for your list of records you want presented in the grid.  Your view model appears to be calling the model to load the list of companies, but you never set the public property

```
IEnumerable<CompanyModel> CompanyDataGrid
```

to anything.  Its just exposed.  You need to set that to the contents retrieved from the model, otherwise it is just null.

For example, your `await model.loadCompanies()` appears to be where you are getting the data from your source, but there is no indication of what else it is doing or returning.  If your loadCompanies can return the  `IList<Company>? _companies` you would just need to adjust something like

```
   private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CompanyDataGrid = await model.loadCompanies();
    }
    private async void updateDataModel()
    {
        // Update the model
        CompanyDataGrid = await model.loadCompanies();
    }
```

This way, not just retrieving the data for the model itself, but passing it back to your view model for display to the end-user to view.

Now, if you want to act on a specific record selected by the user, then make another public property on your view model representing a single company such as

```
public Company SelectedRecordFromGrid {get; set;}
```

and then in your data grid, use the SelectedItem for binding

```
<DataGrid 
   ItemsSource="{Binding CompanyDataGrid, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecordFromGrid}"
   ...rest of your other settings remain... >
```

Then, within the methods in your view model you can act against the `SelectedRecordFromGrid` object.  You could also have the view model do something specific WHEN an entry is selected by defining both parts of the getter/setter such as

```
private Company _selectedRecordFromGrid = null;
public Company SelectedRecordFromGrid 
{
   get { return _selectedRecordFromGrid; }
   set {
           _selectedRecordFromGrid = value;
           if( _selectedRecordFromGrid is null )
               return;
           // else do some other activity.
       }
}
```

But also, at this point, if your SelectedRecordFromGrid is public, and you have other fields on the screen showing all explicit columns for editing vs just showing in the grid, those textboxes could have their Text bindings set to something like

```
<Textbox Text={Binding SelectedRecordFromGrid.Name} .../>
```

Hopefully this can help jump-start you a bit more with WPF and bindings to publicly exposed properties the view can see and work with.

Comment: updateDataModel() must be of type Task and not void!

Answer (score 0):

This is from a working project that is a strict MVVM model. I left out some of the obvious "using" statements and my projects always have separate folders for Models, ViewModels, and Views.

```
    <Window x:Class="TestWpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="CustomerGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Companies}" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCompany}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"
                                    MinWidth="35"
                                    Width="0.1*"
                                    Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                    MinWidth="200"
                                    Width="2*"
                                    Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>


namespace TestWpfApp
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private MainViewModel _viewmodel;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _viewmodel = new MainViewModel();
            this.DataContext = _viewmodel;
        }
    }
}



namespace TestWpfApp.Views
{

    internal class MainViewModel : ViewModels.ViewModelBase
    {

        private ObservableCollection<Company> _Companies = new 
 ObservableCollection<Company>();
        public ObservableCollection<Company> Companies
        {
            get
            { return _Companies; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _Companies)
                {
                    _Companies = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private Company _SelectedCompany = null;
        
        public Company SelectedCompany
        {
            get
            { return _SelectedCompany ?? new Company(); }
            set
            {
                if (value != _SelectedCompany)
                {
                    _SelectedCompany = value ?? new Company();
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            LoadCompanies();
        }

        private void LoadCompanies()
        {
            var companies = new List<Company>();

           companies.Add(new Company { Name = "Acme Corp.", ID = "1" });

            Companies = new ObservableCollection<Company>(companies);
        }
    }
}



namespace TestWpfApp.Models
{
    internal class Company : ViewModels.ViewModelBase
    {


        private String _ID = string.Empty;
        public String ID
        {
            get
            { return _ID ?? string.Empty; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _ID)
                {
                    _ID = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private String _Name = string.Empty;
        public String Name
        {
            get
            { return _Name ?? string.Empty; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _Name)
                {
                    _Name = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}



using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace TestWpfApp.ViewModels
{
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected ViewModelBase() { }
       
        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(Expression<Func<object>> expression) { }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = null) { }

        public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);
    }
}
```